# Centering a table's content to only a part of the page while overflowing the rows to the edges of the screen

Tags: html, twitter-bootstrap, css, html-table

I have a specific way I want my table to look, but I'm struggling to figure out how to make it happen in HTML/CSS/Bootstrap.
I want for its columns to be centered in the center 85%-ish of the screen, with the table itself extending to 100% of the screen.
It should look something like this:
`========|Column|Column|Column|========
 ========|Data  |Data  |Data  |========`

Where the "====" are basically empty space separated by the row borders.

Is there any way to achieve this?

Currently, my table is confined to a bootstrap Container, so it has fixed margins of either side. If I get rid of the container, the table takes up 100% of the page, but the columns also start at the edge.

Any help would be greatly appreciated!

Comment: `table { width: 85vw;}`

Comment: @Banzay he wants the table to be 100% of the screen

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Make 5 columns and give classes to the outer ones, you can set there widths now. If you want the middle to be 85% then each of the outer columns would be 7.5% wide

```css
table {
  width: 100%;
}
.outside {
  width: 7.5%;
}
td {
  border: 1px solid green;
  text-align: center;
}
```

```html
<table>
  <tr>
    <td class="outside">test2</td>
    <td>test</td>
    <td>test</td>
    <td>test</td>
    <td class="outside">test2</td>
  </tr>
  <tr>
    <td class="outside">test2</td>
    <td>test</td>
    <td>test</td>
    <td>test</td>
    <td class="outside">test2</td>
  </tr>
  <table>
```

Comment: Perfect! Exactly what I wanted. Thanks!